# Showing SENT messages in VIP mailbox

Tags: mail.app

Is there any way to modify the VIPs box to show all messages both TO and FROM a particular contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VIP mailbox contains From e-mail *only*. I haven't found an official link from Apple stating this though.

Comment: +1 as I think you're right.. But I want you to be wrong!

Comment: I want me to be too, and if I am, I'll certainly correct it. But in practice, I've been unable to show TO: email in the VIP box. I can certainly see a use case for it.